# How to lazy load widgets with unbounded heights in a CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to lazy load widgets in a `CustomScrollView`, but the children widgets have unbounded heights. When I don't specify a higher `cacheExtent` than the children, the list extremely lags while scrolling and the scroll erratically jumps to another position. On the other hand, giving a high number to `cacheExtent` is breaking the lazy loading even though scrolling is much more smooth.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _children = [
    FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1620)).then(
        (_) => true,
      ),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          height: snap.hasData ? 480 : 320,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text(
            "Widget 1",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 32,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2220)).then(
        (_) => true,
      ),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          height: snap.hasData ? 580 : 350,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text(
            "Widget 2",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 32,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1500)).then(
        (_) => true,
      ),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: snap.hasData ? 600 : 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text(
            "Widget 3",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 32,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 2300)).then(
        (_) => true,
      ),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          height: snap.hasData ? 520 : 170,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text(
            "Widget 4",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 32,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
    FutureBuilder(
      future: Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1800)).then(
        (_) => true,
      ),
      builder: (context, snap) {
        return Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
          height: snap.hasData ? 710 : 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: const Text(
            "Widget 5",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 32,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        // cacheExtent: 8500, // I don't know what to do with cacheExtent
        slivers: <Widget>[
          const SliverAppBar(
            pinned: false,
            snap: false,
            floating: true,
            elevation: 0,
            title: Text(
              'My App',
            ),
          ),
          const SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 20, 0, 22),
              child: Text(
                'My List',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              childCount: _children.length,
              (context, index) => _children[index],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How can I achieve a smooth lazy loading with widgets that have unbounded heights?

Comment: I am not getting any error with the provided example

Comment: There is no error. The issue is laggy scrolling and instantaneous jumps while scrolling.

Comment: Are you using a physical device?

Comment: No, it's Simulator.